# missing .env file in gitlab CI

Tags: environment-variables, gitlab-ci

So I have a react native app in my repo that I'm working on and in my repo I have a .env file that I'm ignoring so that my secrets don't get exposed and a .env-example file of important environment variables to configure. My problem is, since I'm not pushing the .env file to my repo, when I deploy my app through the google app engine(this is done in the deployment stage in my gitlab-ci.yml file), these environment variables will not be present in production and I need them for my app to work as I do something like this in my build.gradle file.

```
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.beecash.app"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    multiDexEnabled true // enabled for adding play service dependency
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 19
    versionName "0.10.1"
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        BRANCH_LIVE_KEY: project.env.get('BRANCH_LIVE_KEY'),
        BRANCH_TEST_KEY: project.env.get('BRANCH_TEST_KEY'),
        BRANCH_TEST_MODE: project.env.get('BRANCH_TEST_MODE'),
        CLEVERTAP_ACCOUNT_ID: project.env.get('CLEVERTAP_ACCOUNT_ID'),
        CLEVERTAP_TOKEN: project.env.get('CLEVERTAP_TOKEN')
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to `.env` file, you can set variables in CI/CD settings through the repository menu:

```
Repository menu > Settings > CI/CD > Variables
```

And easily access them inside CI/CD pipelines and jobs.
For more info you can check [official docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#custom-environment-variables).